# How to start chrome without images in Selenium WebDriver for .NET?

Tags: .net, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying wihout success the following code, but the browser keeps showing the images.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", new string[1] {"disable-images"}); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Selenium WebDriver for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You need Chrome 18+. See http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=17#c1